# Which of these 2 ideas is correct about a "bubble" of false vacuum decay?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, cosmology, universe, vacuum

1. The whole volume of the *bubble* is true vacuum.
2. Only the surface layer of the *bubble* is true vacuum while the interior has turned back to false vacuum.

Comment: The question's useful:  Your possibility #2 may be related to Nikodem Poplawski's torsion-based cosmological model, whose space he's described (in 2010-2021 papers found by his name on Cornell's "Arxiv" website) as shaped like the "skin of a basketball".  The model uses 1929's Einstein-Cartan Theory, which differs from 1915's GR in ECT's assignment of a tiny spatial extent to fermions, which is a key component of his model.  He's compared each local universe in his model to a basketball's skin, with its spatial extent lying between that "skin's" inner & outer surfaces.  In vacuum, ECT=GR.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 is correct.

Think about bubbles in boiling water. Like vacuum decay, boiling water is a phase transition where matter is changing from one state to another. The original state (liquid water) is outside the bubble, and the new state (gaseous water, aka steam) is inside the bubble.